# AJAX Put with json data to ASP.NET Web API method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to do a simple AJAX PUT to my API method. The request is making it to the API method without any errors, but both parameters are not set. They are both 0. Why would this be?

**AJAX Call:**

```
        var data = {
            productId: 100,
            oldIndex: 3
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/products/reorder',
            method: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
```

**API:**

```
        [HttpPut("api/products/reorder")]
        public IActionResult ReOrder([FromBody]int productId, [FromBody]int oldIndex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: If that is a direct copy you have a typo in your url. You start with a single quote but close with a double.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. Typo. As I said I am getting to the method just fine with no errors. It is the params that aren't coming through.

Comment: At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. I would delete both [FromBody] tags.

Comment: @Joe I see so I have to send a single string and then split it? In most cases this is an object so there usually is just one param, but I do not want to make a matching object for this in c# because it is a temporary anonymous object. I just need to get the two values over. I am tempted to put them in the url.

Comment: WebApi should be able to parse what you send without FromBody.

Comment: @Joe Can you give me an example of what my data var should look like then? I will update the api param to be [FromBody] string values. I guess this is the point of Dtos. Maybe I should add an oldIndex property to my Product Dto just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/products/reorder/' + data.productId + '/' + data.oldIndex,
        method: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });


    [HttpPut("api/products/reorder/{productId}/{oldIndex}")]
    public IActionResult ReOrder(int productId, int oldIndex)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works, I guess this is how I should do it. However products is a child entity so my actual web API call is going to be something like this: /api/productgalleries/{id}/products/reorder/{productId}/{oldIndex} or something like that...

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing Yeah attribute routing is really cool!